# insert rows in uitableview and update view immediately

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I would like to implement a search facility in my iPhone application. The functionality is similar to iBooks search where the results are updated row by row and become visible. Also one row is used to view the search progress.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at UISearchDisplayController. It is used together with a UITableView to provide search. You can probably get started by looking [here](http://blog.patrickcrosby.com/2010/04/27/iphone-ipad-uisearchbar-uisearchdisplaycontroller-asynchronous-example.html) or just google with your favorite search engine for UISearchDisplayController.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a background thread to update the table periodically.